# How to integrate prestashop with android?

Tags: php, android, api, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Recently I have created a eshop website using prestashop

https://www.prestashop.com/en/

And since I am going to build the android app for it. What includes in apps are only some basic function

e.g. create customer account / list product / order product / pay / view order etc..common eshop functions...

**The problem is it seems there are few resources around. Is there any library already there/ offical one / or I need to start create the API from stratch?**

read 
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Developer+Guide for a while but no clue what I need to start with so far.

This is quite abstract problem but since the community is not so popular and the resource is limit I hope this can learn from the other's experience and  help any others with the same request.

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Well, writing an API which means you are targeting a native app which do include api building, I hope prestashop provide such options. The least common way to do is to make your site responsive and custom webview app(Phonegap will do that for multiple platforms)

Comment: I looked through the docs and apparently Prestashop does not have any kind of SOAP/REST/XML/JSON-type API which you would need for mobile app integration.  Developing an API for an application of this depth would require a significant amount of effort.  The Prestashop developers would likely increase interest in their product quite a bit if they supplied some sort of an API for integration.  Having an application that can't be expanded into a platform is not an option in today's world.

Comment: Hi, There is no api for Prestashop at present. You will have to create one from scratch to integrate your app to it. Contus mcomm has built a Prestashop api that is ready for launch. The api had several updates that has made it quicker and much more efficient than before. The auto sync facility automatically reflects the changes made in the website back end to the app.

Comment: I guess the above user is right about creating the app from ground up. The api is not available even now on my checking. It is better to opt for a professional service that can create it in a customized fashion. http://www.contus.com/prestashop-mobile-app.php

Comment: As some users have already commented, there is no api for Prestashop at present. If you are looking for a ready to deploy solution, you can try Apphitect's M-Comm. It is a readymade solution that can be launched instantly. It has auto sync, in-store chat, deep linking and several other features you will expect to see in prestashop api. http://www.apphitect.ae/mobile-commerce-app.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is it seems there are few resources around. Is there any library already there/ offical one / or I need to start create the API from stratch?

In contrast to one of the comments on your question, Prestashop *does* actually offer a REST service. In the documentation is it referred to by "web service".

Quick links:

- [Using the Prestashop Web Service](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service)
- [Web service one-page documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+one-page+documentation)
- [Web service tutorial](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial)

There are a few [open source API implementations](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service#UsingthePrestaShopWebService-Implementations) available, but none specifically for Android/Java. You may find them useful as a guideline though.

A few things to take note of:

The web service feature appears to be disabled by default. So in order to use it, you'll have to enable it first in the back-office. Copied from the docs:

> **Enabling the webservice feature**
>
> Go in the PrestaShop back-office, open the "Webservice" page under the
>   "Advanced Parameters" menu, and then choose "Yes" for the "Enable
>   PrestaShop's webservice". Save your change: you're done!

Communicating with the web service requires an API key. You'll have to generate one for your Android app, again using the back-office:

> **Creating an access key**
>
> Open the "Webservice" page under the "Advanced
>   Parameters" menu, and then click the "Add New" button to access the
>   account configuration section. A long form appears:
>
> - **Key**. The API key
>     serves as the main identifier for the webservice account you are
>     creating. Click the "Generate" button to get an unique authentication
>     key. You can also create your own (which must be 32 characters long),
>     but using a generated key prevents wrong-doers from guessing your key
>     too easily. Using this key, you and other selected users will be able
>     to access the webservice.
> - **Key description**. Helps you remember who you
>     created that key for, what are the access rights assigned to it, etc.
>     The description is not public, but make sure to put all the keywords
>     pertaining to the user, so that you can find their key more quickly.
> - **Status**. You can disable any key at any time.
> - **Permissions**. This section
>     is very important, as it enables you to assign rights for each
>     resource you want to make available to this key. Indeed, you might
>     want a user to have read and write access on some resources, but only
>     read access on others – and no access to the more important ones. In
>     the list of permissions, the checkbox most on the left enables you to
>     define all the rights for a given resource. Likewise, the checkbox at
>     the top of each column enables you to give the select right (View,
>     Modify, etc.) to all the resources.  Make sure to only select the
>     rights needed for the usage of that key. Do not give all the rights
>     for all resources to any key, keep that to yours and yours only. Shop
>     association. This only appears in multistore mode. It enables you to
>     choose which of your stores the key owner should have access to.
>
> If
>   you choose to use a custom passkey instead of a generated one, make
>   sure it is very secure and that its rights are limited – and that it
>   is 32characters long!

Finally, to get an overview of the API methods:

> **Accessing the webservice from the browser**
>
> The endpoint to your store's
>   webservice is located in the `/api/` folder at the root of your
>   installation of Prestashop:
>
> - If PrestaShop is installed at the root of
>     your server, you can access the API here: http://example.com/api/
> - If
>     PrestaShop is installed in a subfolder of your server, you can access
>     the API here: http://example.com/prestashop/api/
>
> To access it, you
>   need to provide your API key when request. There is no password,
>   providing your API key is enough – and therefore the key should be
>   kept secret by the user! You can either type the API endpoint address
>   directly then enter your API key, or indicate your API key in the
>   address. Here is an example, with `UCCLLQ9N2ARSHWCXLT74KUKSSK34BFKX`
>   being the API key.
>
> - At the root of the server:
>     http://UCCLLQ9N2ARSHWCXLT74KUKSSK34BFKX@example.com/api/
> - In a
>     subfolder of the server:
>     http://UCCLLQ9N2ARSHWCXLT74KUKSSK34BFKX@example.com/prestasshop/api/
>
> You can test this with any browser that supports XML. If no permission
>   has been set for the key, then the browser will keep asking you to
>   enter the key indefinitely.

The result should look somewhat like this (for version 1.5.4.1 of PrestaShop):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <api shop_name="MYSHOP">
    <addresses>...</addresses>
    <carriers>...</carriers>
    <cart_rules>...</cart_rules>
    <carts>...</carts>
    <categories>...</categories>
    <combinations>...</combinations>
    <configurations>...</configurations>
    <contacts>...</contacts>
    <content_management_system>...</content_management_system>
    <countries>...</countries>
    <currencies>...</currencies>
    <customer_messages>...</customer_messages>
    <customer_threads>...</customer_threads>
    <customers>...</customers>
    <deliveries>...</deliveries>
    <employees>...</employees>
    <groups>...</groups>
    <guests>...</guests>
    <image_types>...</image_types>
    <images>...</images>
    <languages>...</languages>
    <manufacturers>...</manufacturers>
    <order_carriers>...</order_carriers>
    <order_details>...</order_details>
    <order_discounts>...</order_discounts>
    <order_histories>...</order_histories>
    <order_invoices>...</order_invoices>
    <order_payments>...</order_payments>
    <order_states>...</order_states>
    <orders>...</orders>
    <price_ranges>...</price_ranges>
    <product_feature_values>...</product_feature_values>
    <product_features>...</product_features>
    <product_option_values>...</product_option_values>
    <product_options>...</product_options>
    <product_suppliers>...</product_suppliers>
    <products>...</products>
    <search >...</search>
    <shop_groups>...</shop_groups>
    <shops>...</shops>
    <specific_price_rules>...</specific_price_rules>
    <specific_prices>...</specific_prices>
    <states>...</states>
    <stock_availables>...</stock_availables>
    <stock_movement_reasons>...</stock_movement_reasons>
    <stock_movements>...</stock_movements>
    <stocks>...</stocks>
    <stores>...</stores>
    <suppliers>...</suppliers>
    <supply_order_details>...</supply_order_details>
    <supply_order_histories>...</supply_order_histories>
    <supply_order_receipt_histories>...</supply_order_receipt_histories>
    <supply_order_states>...</supply_order_states>
    <supply_orders>...</supply_orders>
    <tags>...</tags>
    <tax_rule_groups>...</tax_rule_groups>
    <tax_rules>...</tax_rules>
    <taxes>...</taxes>
    <translated_configurations>...</translated_configurations>
    <warehouse_product_locations>...</warehouse_product_locations>
    <warehouses>...</warehouses>
    <weight_ranges>...</weight_ranges>
    <zones>...</zones>
  </api>
  <api shop_name="MYOTHERSHOP">...</api>
  <api shop_name="YETANOTHERSHOP">...</api>
</prestashop>
```

Since you mention you're mainly interested in supporting basic/core functionality in the Android app, I'm inclined to say this probably fits your needs. :)

Comment: thanks for you great effort, that means perstrashop already has rest service provide , all I need to do is to get those API link and post /get data from it

Comment: @MH.. is it possible to guide me as to how to make the service call from android? I get 401 when i am passing the key also :( .

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: I suggest you start a new question here on SO. Without any implementation details it's shooting in the dark at what might be wrong.

Comment: @MH - thanks.. il just do so.. and post in my link here.. so that u cud help ..

Comment: @MH. -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411979/401-error-when-connecting-to-prestashop-webservice-from-android

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking for a native app, you may want to try a responsive [mobile template addon](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/mobile/6165-prestashop-mobile-template-14.html) or [paid themes](http://module-presta.com/themes-2.html?p=1). If you need a native app and would like to reuse APIs from your prestashop store, you will have to [create an access](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Chapter+1+-+Creating+Access+to+Back+Office) to [Prestashop REST webservices](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Using+the+REST+webservice)

To test if you have properly configured your access to the web service, go to the page http://mypasskey@mystore.com/api/, where "mypasskey" is replaced by your key.