# 401 Error when connecting to PrestaShop webservice from android

Tags: android, web-services, prestashop

I am trying to call a webservice in PrestaShop but i get 401 not authorized error. Even though i have passed the username key. I tried the authenticator too but i get an error HttpRetryingError.

Find below the code snippet of what i have done.

**Method one:**

```
final String username = "key_here";
final String password = "";// leave it empty

URL urlToRequest = new URL(urlStr);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
"text/xml;charset=utf-8");

String authToBytes = username + ":" + password;
//....
byte[] authBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(authToBytes.getBytes());
String authBytesString = new String(authBytes);
//then your code
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic " + authBytesString);

int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode(); ---> i get 401
if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
// throw some exception
InputStream in =
new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
Log.e("tag", getResponseText(in));
}
```

**Method two**

```
final String username = "keyvaluehere";
final String password = "";// leave it empty
String authToBytes = username + ":" + password;
byte[] authBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(authToBytes.getBytes());
String authBytesString = new String(authBytes);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
// Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
// The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
int timeoutConnection = 30000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
int timeoutSocket = 30000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization","Basic " +authBytesString);
try {
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
return strResponse;
}
return strResponse;
}catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I even tried passing the string as ws_key and the keyvalue and i even called the url as http://keyvalue@domain.com/api/namehere

but it doesn't work too.
Please assist.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old question, but I think I can help.

Check .htaccess file. It should has lines like these:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The second line tell Apache how to process the authorization.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks ! In my case it was a Prestashop 1.6.1.24, and the second line was missing.