# Migrate my E-commercial website on mobile phone platform using PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, prestashop, phonegap-desktop-app

I have just created a website based on prestahsop template (PHP + SMARTY), and I have made it work online.

Now I want to migrate the project on mobiles. I searched for several means of doing that, finally I am about to use PhoneGap for my solution.

But I have no idea if that can encapsulate the whole project on the mobile platform, and ideally be launched on Apple store. If not, I would like to get some advice to make changes.

Anyone having former experience can come to help? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to andre3wap response, you can use [Prestashop Webservice API](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service) to link your application to your website. I've already done this in the past, the tricky part comes when you need to create an order in your Prestashop website from your application. But it's completely doable.

You will have to create an `HTML` + `Javascript` application with PhoneGap, that calls Prestashop via `Ajax` requests. If you want your application to work offline (and only create the order when the customer is back online) you will have to load every products on installation and sync when the app is online.

It's a lot of work.

---

**EDIT** [related question: How to integrate prestashop with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724731/how-to-integrate-prestashop-with-android)

Comment: Many thanks for your help, your answer is quite useful! And at the same time, I am wondering if I create a native app, possibly using Java, will that be comparably easier, as I saw you mentioned "It's a lot of work" :D.

Comment: If you have knowledge in native app, their will be no over development needed compared to a PhoneGap app. The call to the api will still be the same but you'll be able to handle your local product base synchronisation more easily and flawlessly.

Comment: So far, I have only found the tutorials about prestashop web service, creating APIs for my initial web application. Somewhere I can not totally understand, and to connect the apis cprresponding to my local app. And for native apps, I only had former expericenc in android development. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks a million for your warm help!

Comment: I've added a link to a related question to my answer. If you have any more questions please open a new Question with your specific problem because this one is quite broad. If you find my answer useful can you accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If your web site only consists of `HTML` pages, yes; PhoneGap will be able to do most of the work(Just upload your HTML pages in a folder to build.phonegap.com for the conversion), there are other methods that can do the conversion, but that one is easier to me. (Read their documentation)

If your web site was created from a server side language, `NO`, phoneGap will not be able to fully convert it into a full fledged HyBrid App.

It gets very tricky when it comes on to Server Side scripting + phoneGap. What you can do is build html pages, and create "APIs" to load the data in the APP and use JavaScript to parse the data respectfully. (That phoneGap can handle)

You can read this article for an even more detailed explanation:
[Usefull Article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/05/05/converting-a-dynamic-web-site-to-a-phonegap-application/)