# Is it possible to access the Prestashop's Web service by client (customer) login instead the key?

Tags: javascript, web-services, react-native, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm studying Prestashop's development. And I trying to create a "third part" side application with react.js (React Native for more precision) and catch Json data in the prestashop's webservice. But I want to let the "customer" make login with his own account and only his account. With CRUD also.

in advance; Very thank you for your patience and attention.

Best Regards.

Michel Diz

Comment: And I found this (But ain't enough) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724731/how-to-integrate-prestashop-with-android/28925554?newreg=e51eb8f5ed03430f80392eef2a983df0

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Actually It's just a question. I'm not asking to do the code for me. I'm asking if it's possible and if someone knows where I find the information. But I'll organize a logical code argument to see if anyone catch it.

Best Regards.

Comment: PrestaShop has its API and its webservices, all is in the official documentation that you can find [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/English+documentation). However, I'm here to help others when the questions are more specific and when people can't figure out the errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop backoffice login give no access to webservices. Webservices must be enabled and a key generated. So, I recommend you that change your "login" way. Customers accounts are not related with webservices and webservices are only used to access stored data un Prestashop (more like Backoffice than Frontoffice).

What exactly do you need to do?

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I kind knew about this.
I'm thinking try something with Firebase Auth.
Before I was thinking to integrate my current test app made in the React Native. And then consume everything by Json generated in the Prestashop's Web service.

Comment: inside my test app, I was thinking to do a serie of actions in the code. Using first of all the Web Service with the generated key and then filtering the user after the pass by the some intern auth confirmation. But now I wanna try Firebase auth.

Comment: All Prestashop API doc here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still searching for a solution but there is a way actually.

**DO MAKE SURE IT IS A SECURE LOGIN.**

Since you're giving access to all prestashop data do make sure the login is very secure. I've been able to recreate it with `PHP` I think that with some additions you're able to recreate it the way you want it. See it as a guideline.

To create a login system by using the prestashop webservice you'll need three things

Access through webservice to the customers table
The COOKIE_KEY, defined in app/config -> parameters.php:: 'cookie_key' => '12321test';
Some expierence with PHP
The first thing is to get the customers table from the webservice.

```
// code placeholder
require_once('./../PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

/**
 * get information from PrestaShop
 */

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $key, $debug);

$COOKIE_KEY = 'CookieKey';
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$optUser = array(
    'resource' => 'customers',
    'filter[email]' => '[' . $email . ']',
    'display' => '[id,email,lastname,firstname,passwd]'
);

$resultUser = ($webService->get($optUser));

$json = json_encode($resultUser);
```

The second and most important thing is to Check the user input

```
// code placeholder

foreach ($resultUser->customers->customer as $info) {
    // Prestashop uses the cookie_key in combination with a salt key. To check the password use the php function: password_verify();
    $salt = substr($info->passwd, strrpos($info->passwd, ':') + 1, 2);
    $ZCpassword = md5($COOKIE_KEY . $password) . ':' . $salt;

    // Check if password comparison is true or false
    if (password_verify($password, $info->passwd) == true) {
        session_start();
        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = 'succes';
        $response['message'] = "You did it!";
        setcookie("userId", $info->id);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = 'Wrong password';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

This is how to reproduce the issue to a working example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. At the moment I can not test your approach, since I completely changed my stack in the meantime. However, I can re-test soon.

And If someone takes your code and continues. Delivering positive results I'll mark your response as the solution.

A little later on this question I made here I was able to make a small Node GraphQL API that consumed as a "bridge" the prestashop database directly with sequelize. However, I had to stop because I needed to work on another project.

 Looking at it seems to me to be a good approach.

Thank you anyway. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still searching for this answer,

```
<?

if (isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["password"]) )
{
$email =  $_GET["email"];
$password = $_GET["password"];

$COOKIE_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$jsonurl = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@example.com/api/customers?filter[email]=".$email."&display=[passwd]&output_format=JSON";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json_a = json_decode($json, true);

$loopone = $json_a['customers'];
$looptwo = $loopone[0];
$loopthree = $looptwo['passwd'];

$ZCpassword = md5($COOKIE_KEY . $password);

if (strcmp($loopthree, $ZCpassword) == 0) {
        echo "sucess";
    } else {
         echo "fail";
    }

}
else
{
    echo "Send something with url dude";
}

?>
```